# Can two Android "clients" use the video camera at the same time?

Tags: android, qr-code, google-hangouts

Perhaps "clients" is not the correct word - "activities", perhaps?

Specifically, I need to create an Android app that uses ZXing or similar to detect QR Codes while a video chat (Google Hangouts API or similar) is happening at the same time. Sometimes there will be a person in front of the Android camera, but most of the time the app will be scanning for QR codes that pass by.

Alternatively, I could use Google Hangouts and a custom ZXing app running at the same time. Is that possible?

I'm a novice on Android, so thanks in advance!

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Android doesn't allow you to use both cameras at the same time. However you should be able to if you code from the base.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - one camera feeding two apps or activities.